# Phoenix JDBC query - Joins does not work

Tags: apache-phoenix

Hello Phoenix Team and friends working on Phoenix/Hbase,

I am connecting to Phoenix layer on HBase using JDBC Driver. My PreparedStatement with simple select query works/executes fine in my Java program. However, when I use any sql join (left, or inner) the PreparedStatement execute query gives below expection even thought I limit my results to 1 or 5 records.

**java.sql.SQLException: Encountered exception in sub plan [0] execution.**

However when I run the same query (Simple or Joins) works well on Phoenix client.

Did anyone face this issue?
Please share if any fix around

Best regards,
Nandu

Comment: no expertise on phoenix?

Comment: Can you try this, I think its jar issue.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730643/phoenix-join-operation-not-working-with-hbase][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730643/phoenix-join-operation-not-working-with-hbase

Answer (score 2):

Please use the hint /*+ NO_STAR_JOIN */ to execute your query. There are some more hints which can help you to fine tune your query based on the nature of operation which you want to perform.Please refer to hints at this link https://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html

Comment: In my case the `/*+ USE_SORT_MERGE_JOIN */` was the hint that works for an `INNER JOIN`