# phoenix join operation not working with hbase

Tags: database, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am using `hbase-1.1.0.1` and `phoenix-4.4.0-HBase-1.1-bin` versions. To run SQL query I am using `SQuirrel` SQL client.

Simple queries such as `Select *`, `Select count(*)`, `where clause` and sub queries are working fine, but `JOIN` operation is not working at all. Please help me on this.

Comment: Can you show us the query that isn't working?  I would expect that it is an issue with the SQL.

Comment: Ho Degustaf the query was :Select o.orderid, c.contactname from orders as o INNER JOIN customers as c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID;

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. Actually I did a mistake where I copied "phoenix-core-4.4.0-HBase-1.1.jar" into my hbase's lib directory. When I replaced it with "phoenix-4.4.0-HBase-1.1-server.jar" problem got resolved ! Now join operation is working.